# why is the NL solution PATH negated unsufficient to prove unreachability

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm currently reading into complexity classes and one think will not fit into my head.
We are investigating NLogSpace with the Path/reachability problem.
There is a nondeterministic LogSpace algorithm which can solve reachability, but its inversion does not prove nonreachability because "it could miss a path". How is it possible to miss a path? Wouldn't it imply that the reachability test might doesn't work? 
Can somebody please explain it to me? Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what algorithm you are envisioning would be "the inversion" of the reachability algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe i was a bit to specific, i had a general misunderstanding in how non-deterministic machines work. Here is what i figured:

an accepting nondeterministic turing machine always gives the right answer ("found something, therefore a solution exists",
on the other hand, a reject means "did not find anything" which is not the same as "there is no solution"

therefore a reject can't be trusted and any algorithm which uses a reject from a non deterministic (Existance) machine has to double check. Also this implies, that a non-deterministic machine could give a false negative.